# Displaying results where count equals value

Tags: powershell, count, where-clause

I want to identify the top few processes by average CPU usage over a period of couple of seconds. Each result needs to list the PID, Process Name and UserID. 
The script needs to be run on several servers at the same time that are in another domain. The credentials for those servers are different to the computer it is being run from.

I can’t get `Get-Process` to work as it doesn’t accept the `–credentials` parameter.
`Invoke-Command` will not work as scripting is restricted on these servers.
What I’ve ended up with in `$TopProcess` is:

```
User Name                   CPU       ID Description                                     
---------                   ---       -- -----------                                     
User73                       25    68680 App89.exe                              
User73                       25    68888 App57.exe                               
LOCAL SERVICE               2.5    63868 WmiPrvSE.exe                                    
User48                        0    66308 App38.exe                                     
User48                        0    62608 App54.exe                         
User73                       25    68888 App57.exe                               
User73                       25    68680 App89.exe                              
LOCAL SERVICE               2.5    63868 WmiPrvSE.exe                                    
User48                        0    59336 dwm.exe                                         
User48                        0    52528 App57.exe                               
User73                       25    68888 App57.exe                               
User73                       25    68680 App89.exe                              
User39                     19.5    48792 App43.exe                      
User39                      2.5    65996 App48.exe                              
LOCAL SERVICE               2.5    63868 WmiPrvSE.exe
```

but I need to list only the results that have a CPU over 15 and are listed three times but only to list each once and

```
$Result = $TopProcess | Where {$_.CPU -gt $Threshold} | Measure | Where {$_.Count -eq $NoRS}
```

returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Group-Object` cmdlet instead of `Measure` to group your result. I think you only want to get the `UserName` property:

```
$Result = $TopProcess | 
    Where {$_.CPU -gt $Threshold} | 
    group 'User Name' |  
    Where Count -eq $NoRS | 
    select Name
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Martin. Based on the example I'd expect to see only the top two lines: 

`User73  25 68680 App89.exe 
User73 25 68888 App57.exe` 

I tried using `Group` and my `If (!$Result)` shows it returns null too.

Comment: Oh, then you have to also group for the ID.

Comment: I split each pipe to a new variable to check and `Group` gives the expected counts. I now need to reformat the grouped result back to a readable table.